# Java exception when writing PDF with iTextPDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, itextpdf

I'm trying to write a PDF, more specifically write as a HMTL page, using iTextPdf and XMLWorkerHelper, using verions 5.5.9 of both.

But when I try to write to the PDF I get an exception, NoSuchMethodError, no clue as to what is causing this.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph.setRole(Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfName;)V
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Header.end(Header.java:97)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.endElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:229)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.close(HtmlPipeline.java:208)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:142)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:397)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:71)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:239)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:211)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:184)
```

Hoping someone can shed some light in this matter, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This almost always means that you compiled against one version of a library (in this case, iText) but you are deploying with a different version.

Check the versions in both environments and verify that they are both, in fact, 5.5.9

Comment: well, I'm debugging this as a part of a JUnit test, and in the project classpath (using Eclipse) I have only one iText entry (used to have an older one though).

Comment: well, guess what, had some other itext jars inside a related project folder, guess it was it, even though they were not declared in the classpath. Thanks